# Where i can find CCleaner InstallDate? (forensics)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, forensics, ccleaner

I have tried in

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

without finding anything

any suggestions?

Comment: Does the creation date of the directory it was installed in help?

Comment: The CREATED tag in "CCupdate.ini" it was helpul

Comment: (1) Do you want date of initial installation or date of most recent update (i.e., installation of the *current* version)? (2) Where is `CCupdate.ini`?

Comment: I want the date of initial installation, CCupdate.ini is in the root directory of CCleaner

Answer (score 0):

In Control Panel open Programs and Features, in there it will show the install date.

Comment: It should be noted that this shows the date of most recent update (i.e., installation of the *current* version) and not the date of initial installation.